# How to get Value inside anchor tag from DocumentElementById?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to print 'back' , but getting undefined
       " http://jsbin.com/arecey/77/ "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `innerHTML` property, like this

```
console.log(anchorobject.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 2):

do this:

```
//incorrect
anchorobject.value;

//correct
anchorobject.innerHTML;
```